# why does the VFP code ENDIF-*9 work

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have inherited VFP code that has an IF  Endif statement where the endif is coded ENDIF-*9  For whatever reason this gets past the compiler, and generates no run time errors.  Anyone know why this works?

Answer (score 1):

It is not specific to ENDIF. It would also work for endfor, enddo, endscan ... I think VFP only cares about seeing the word "endif" and discards rest as comment.

Comment: that seems to be true, however if you put any other character in place or in front of the "-" it will gen a compile time error.  So, does this have special meaning to VFP?

Comment: I meant any character acts as a separator for "word". So it is sufficient for it to see "endif" as a "word". Any letter, underscore or digit would make it a different "word" and thus syntax error. Those characters are the one used for names in VFP.

Answer (score 1):

From the Help for DO WHILE ... ENDDO:

```
Comments can be placed after DO WHILE and ENDDO on the same line. The comments are ignored during program compilation and execution.
```

I've known that and always assumed that was the case.  In your example, though, you're not leaving any space between the end of the keyword and the start of the 'extra' text.  My guess would be that the lexer in VFP recognizes - (and I tested + as well) as a terminator for the ENDIF (or ENDDO, etc) and treats the rest of the line as a comment.  If you just have extra stuff immediately after ENDIF (like ENDIFblah), VFP doesn't recognize the keyword and treats it as junk, resulting in a syntax error.